# Google Cloud Speech: word start time

Tags: audio, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I'm looking at using Google Cloud Speech to convert long-form narrated audio files and I need to know the start time of each phrase in the audio file.  Is there a way to do this with Google Cloud Speech?
I'm currently working with the `transcribe_async.py`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with Google Cloud Speech.  If that information is important to you, you may need to look at other ASR systems.  I know that offline, non-hosted ASR systems like [Kaldi](http://kaldi-asr.org/) and [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) will give you this information.  I don't know if or which hosted ASR systems can provide that information.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can get (aproximated) start and end times (from the beginning of the audio track) for each word by setting to True the enableWordTimeOffsets option: https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/async-time-offsets.

Beware that the start time of the first word of the transcript is always 0 and that, as far as I know, each word start time correspond to the previous word end time (also if there are pauses).

Comment: Is there any way to find out the real start value for the first element ?